# Backpropagation with numpy makes weights NaN

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, nan, backpropagation

for some reason my backprop algorithm makes my weights NaN, I have no idea why. Its not all the time, as well, seems random. I don't know what makes NaN occur, but it would help if anyone could explain. Here is the code for backprop:

```
def backpropagate(self, data, iters=1, learning_rate=0.001):
        inputs = [_set[0] for _set in data]
        outputs = [_set[1] for _set in data]
        for i in range(iters):
            for j in range(len(inputs)):
                output = outputs[j]
                input = inputs[j]
                expected = self.feed_forward(input)  # expected output
                state = self.feed_full(input)
                error = output - expected  # error
                delta = error * self.activation_function(expected, True)
                self.weights[len(self.weights) - 1] += np.transpose(state[len(self.weights)]).dot(delta) * learning_rate
                for weight_layer in reversed(range(len(self.weights))):
                    i = weight_layer
                    error = delta.dot(self.weights[i].T)  # updating error
                    delta = error * self.activation_function(state[i], True)  # updating delta for each weight
                    self.weights[i] += np.transpose(state[i]).dot(delta) * learning_rate
```

here is the simple feed forward for all states of the network:

```
def feed_full(self, x):
    state = x
    activations = [x]
    for weight_layer in self.weights:
        state = self.activation_function(np.dot(state, weight_layer))
        activations.append(state)
    return activations
```

Here is the main file:

```
data = [[[1, 2], 3],
        [[2, 2], 4],
        [[3, 2], 5],
        [[1, 1], 2],
        [[0, 2], 2]]

input_set = [_set[0] for _set in data]

nn = NeuralNetwork([2, 1], linear)
print(nn.feed_forward(input_set))
nn.print_net()
nn.backpropagate(data, 10000)
nn.print_net()
print(nn.feed_forward(input_set))
```

I should mention that the activation function is a class, here:

```
class ActivationFunction:
    def __init__(self, func, deriv):
        self.func = func
        self.deriv = deriv

    def __call__(self, x, deriv=False):
        if not deriv:
            return self.func(x)
        return self.deriv(x)
```

also here is a log of the deltas and errors for some iterations when the shape of the network is [2, 30, 1]. Doing 10000 iterations:

```
Delta: [-1.25834964e+20]
Error: [-5.39488342e+132]
Delta: [-5.39488342e+132]
Error: [-inf]
Delta: [-inf]
Error: [-inf]
Delta: [-inf]
Error: [nan]
Delta: [nan]
Error: [nan]
Delta: [nan]
```

All of the activation functions work fine, but I keep getting NaN. Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried debugging your code? Why don't you share a minimal reproducible example? The error might appear in functions you haven't provided such as `self.feed_forward, self.activation_function`

Comment: Have you tried reducing the learning rate?

Comment: Mikhail Berlinkov - Well, to be honest I am not that great at debugging however I believe the problem lies in how small the error gets, it gets pretty small. I not sure what makes NaN appear so I don't know how to make an example. I'll give the code for `self.feed_forward` at the end. `self.activation_function` most likely is not the problem, considering I am using a linear activation, where f(x) = x and f'(x) = 1.
    `def feed_forward(self, x):

        for weight_layer in self.weights:

            x = self.activation_function(np.dot(x, weight_layer))

        return x`

Comment: Mark F. - Reducing the learning rate works, but only to an extent. It allows more iterations without NaN appearing, but it eventually does. If I want larger neural networks to work, I would need an average learning rate with a large amount of iterations.

Comment: Are you sure `self.weights[i] += np.transpose(state[i]).dot(delta) * learning_rate` is correct? Shouldn't you subtract the gradient instead of adding?

Comment: @cheersmate I know, that makes sense, I saw it and it confused me, but it works with `+=`, I tried subtracting but it didn't work. However, that might be causing the error. It seems that the delta and error reach infinity and that is what makes it NaN, not sure how my algorithm is wrong, though.

Comment: If you keep moving in the direction of the gradient (by adding it and not subtracting it), the error will increase towards infinity. You say "it didn't work with subtracting", in what way does it not work?

Comment: @cheersmate - When I subtract it, it predicts it wrong, and doesn't learn. If you look at the algorithm, I worked it out on paper for a perceptron trying to do basic addition, adding the gradient works for some reason. I'm not exactly sure why, but it does.